# Wait till PDF File is finished?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some problems when ill create a PDF from a form - there are multiple pages (up to 20 and i want to create the file in a background thread)

I would like to use an completion handler, so when the file is created i want to show it in an QLPreviewController. But when ill use no wait/sleep function it always crashes with an error, that the file is not already finished.

So at the moment:

```
func exportPDF(fileName:String, task: completionHandler:(success:Bool) -> Void) {
    // run on background
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

        // write pages

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        completionHandler(success:true) // how do i wait till file has finshed?
    })
}
```

Ill call with:

```
exportPDF(filepath, task: task, completionHandler:{(success:Bool) -> Void in

        let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

        dispatch_after(when, queue) {

            if self.finish == true {

                let preview = ExportQLPreviewController()
                preview.task = self.task
                preview.dataSource = self
                preview.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 700)
                preview.emaildelegate = self.emaildelegate

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)


            } else {

                let preview = QLPreviewController()
                preview.dataSource = self
                preview.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 700)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)

            }

        }

})
```

Is there something wrong? How can ill wait till my file has written? Because without the "wait" method it always crashes (it looks like that the completion handler does not wait till the UIGraphicsEndPDFContext() finish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dispatch_group.

```
    //Create a dispatch_group
    let taskGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    //Set a start label before your function
    dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup)
    //Put a end label after your function finished
    dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup)
    //And dispatch_group_notify will be called while
    //number of enter labels = number of end labels
    dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //Do what you want after task is finished.
    })
```

like this

[image]

Comment: How can you get the PDF contenxt on background thread? From the global queue I alway get `invalid context 0x0` error.